# Mpchartlib in Android remove slice text from piechart

Tags: android, pie-chart

[image]

HI..
I have used https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart to display piechart in my application. I want to hide portion displayed in white square in image.

I have used following code..

```
 mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
        mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(false);
        mChart.setRotationAngle(90);
        mChart.setRotationEnabled(false);
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        mChart.setCenterText(PTGConstantMethod.getNumberInTwoDigit((float) total));
        mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(fontBold);
        mChart.setCenterTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_rate_circle_size));
        mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setDrawSliceText(false);
        setChartData(aryVals, total);



        mChart.animateXY(1000, 1000);

        mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

And my method to set data is..

```
  private void setChartData(float[] values,double total) {

    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        yVals.add(new Entry(values[i], i));
    }

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        xVals.add("");
    }


    PieDataSet set1 = new PieDataSet(yVals, "");
    set1.setSliceSpace(0);

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#009a20"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#5bc0de"));
    set1.setColors(colors);

    PieData data = new PieData(xVals,set1);

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.highlightValues(null);
    mChart.invalidate();



}
```

Anyone can help me to hide these value?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the slice text (coming from the x-values array), call:

`pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false)`

Comment: i am passing "" in  x-values array as you can see in this code. The values getting printed is the values  in yVals array.
I had tried by pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false) but it's not working

Comment: If you are talking about the y-values, call `pieDataSet.setDrawValues(false)`

Comment: mChart.setDrawValues(false); -> method not resolved -> method not found

but yes..             mChart.getData().setDrawValues(false); worked. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: mChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false); please use this method as the above one is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

`pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false)` can remove the xVals
`pieChart.getData().setDrawValues(false)` can remove the yVals

Comment: Yes. Philipp Jahoda has already specified this in his comments.

Comment: setDrawSliceText(false) this method is deprecated 

 mChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false); use this instead

Answer (score 2):

```
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(values, "xyz");
dataSet.setDrawValues(false); // It removes text from chart
```

Comment: Worked !! Thanks Buddy

Comment: but the method is now deprecated in new versions what to with that

Comment: mChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false); in this case use this method as the previous one is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false) is deprecated, use setDrawEntryLabels(...) instead.

```
pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false)
```